# fix slicker unslick issue angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im using this extension insteal of the orginal one, cause its angularjs : http://vasyabigi.github.io/angular-slick/

orginal slick (jquery) : http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

but when i use it, and click on it i get:

```
angular.js:13920 TypeError: slider.unslick is not a function
    at lib/angular-slick/dist/slick.js:60:20
    at /lib/angular/angular.js:19612:31
    at completeOutstandingRequest (/lib/angular/angular.js:5964:10)
    at /lib/angular/angular.js:6243:7 undefined
```

snippet of slick.js:60:20:

```
destroySlick = function () {
      return $timeout(function () {
        var slider;
        slider = $(element);
        slider.unslick();
        slider.find('.slick-list').remove();
        return slider;
      });
    };
```

failed at:

```
 slider.unslick();
```

any idea how i would solve my unslick problem?

if i change

```
  slider.unslick();
```

to

```
    slider.slick('unslick');
```

then my ng-clicks wont execute when im clicking them again.

Comment: In my opinion this is an "error" or not-so-safe-implementation in the directive.  There should always be sanity checks when doing things like this, i.e the code should be something like `if (slider && slider.slick) slider.slick('unslick');` You could raise it as an issue or make a pull request yourself.

Comment: I tried @davidkonrad but i GOT no reply for ages

Answer (score 0):

from documentation - `slider.slick('unslick');`

Comment: you can't get slider.unslick is not a function, because you dont call it. which error do you have?

Comment: if i do slider.slick('unslick');

then my next ng-click fails and wont execute